# Problem with foreach in \node with rectangle split

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am attempting to automate the use `rectangle split parts` with a `foreach` loop. In the following MWE, the manual use of `\nodepart` works as expected. The `\foreach` loop fails with

```
./makebox-mwe.tex:71: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\pgfutil@reserved@c ->\egroup 
                              \relax 
l.71 \end{outerenv}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

%% Thanks to egreg, make lrbox* global (requires etoolbox.sty):
\cslet{glrbox}\lrbox
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname glrbox\endcsname{\setbox}{\global\setbox}{}{}
\cslet{endglrbox}\endlrbox

\newsavebox{\myboxi}    
\newsavebox{\myboxii}   
\newsavebox{\myboxiii}
\newsavebox{\myboxiv}   
\newsavebox{\myboxv}

\newcounter{myboxes}

\def\numname#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven \or twelve\or thirteen\or fourteen\or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eighteen\or nineteen\or twenty\fi%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{outerenv}{}{%
    \setcounter{myboxes}{0}%
}{%
    \tikz \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=5,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
    {%
        %% This does NOT work:
        \foreach \nn in {1,...,\themyboxes}{%
        \edef\tmpname{\csname mybox\romannumeral\nn\endcsname}\typeout{\tmpname}%
        \def\tmpnum{\numname{\nn}}\typeout{\tmpnum}%
        \nodepart{\tmpnum}\usebox{\tmpname}%
        }%
        %%%
        %% This works:
%       \nodepart{one}{\usebox{\myboxi}}
%       \nodepart{two}{\usebox{\myboxii}}
%       \nodepart{three}{\usebox{\myboxiii}}
%       \nodepart{four}{\usebox{\myboxiv}}
%       \nodepart{five}{\usebox{\myboxv}}%
    };%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerenv}{}{%
    \stepcounter{myboxes}%
    \edef\tmpname{\csname mybox\romannumeral\themyboxes\endcsname}%\typeout{\tmpname}%
    \begin{glrbox}{\tmpname}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
}{%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{glrbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{outerenv}

\begin{innerenv}
First
\end{innerenv}

\begin{innerenv}
Second
\end{innerenv}

\begin{innerenv}
Third
\end{innerenv}

\end{outerenv}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE:** I know that there are probably a million (gajillion?) other ways of doing this. But my curiosity is piqued as to why this apparently straightforward attempt fails.

Comment: With an `\xintFor*` loop, it works with a single line: `\nodepart{\numname{##1}}\usebox{\csname mybox\romannumeral##1\endcsname}`. Thus I guess the problem is that `\nodepart` does not like being scoped. Maybe you can use the un-scoping foreach loop from pgfplots?

Comment: @jfbu Thank you, but could you flesh that out a bit? I tried `\xintFor* ##1 in {1,2,3,4,5} \do {\nodepart{\numname{##1}}\usebox{\csname mybox\romannumeral##1\endcsname}}` but TeX complains of a `Missing \begin{document}`

Comment: @jfbu Oops. My bad. After fixing some silly errors, it is working. Thanks.

Comment: the `\xintFor*` starred variant is for use with `in {12345}` or `in {\xintSeq{1}{5}}` (too lazy to have done the `1, ..., 5` type syntax but I will... it would be 1...5 here). The non-starred variant `\xintFor` is for `in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and there is no macro for generating thes csv values (there is one in `xintexpr` which recognizes `a..b` but it  has private name). Anyway, glad you got it working :)

Comment: Quite deliriously happy using `{\xintSeq{<n_1>}{<n_m>}` ;). Works like a charm! A puzzle (not entirely surprising perhaps) that `\foreach` and `\nodepart` do not seem to play well together. Ah well, live and learn...

Comment: if inside the `\xintFor*` loop I surround the `\nodepart...` with `\begingroup...\endgroup` I reproduce exactly the error you report. Thus I think this is really the problem: `\nodepart` can not be used inside a group (or environment). That `\foreach` executes each iteration in a group is the topic of probably hundreds if not thousands questions here :) thus I was kind of expecting this as root cause.

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much.  I was incorrect in assuming that the braces enclosing the working code of `\foreach` was the group. It is clear to me now that *each iteration* is a group. Always nice to learn something. Thanks.  Yes, I've seen the innumerable questions about this. Sometimes it takes a long time for the penny to drop.

Comment: the braces enclosing the working code are (I presume) like the braces for any typical argument to a LaTeX command: a macro fetches the whole thing and removes them in so-doing. The group is explicitely introduced internally by `\foreach`, in order to easier nest. (because inner loops will not contaminate structure of outer loop). The `\xintFor` does not use groups, and does nest ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears one can not use `\nodepart{..}` inside a group (e.g. `{\nodepart{...}}` or inside a LaTeX environment).

Alternative is to use some looping not using groups. For example the `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` or `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` of [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

As a poor man alternative you have lightweight package `xinttools` which provides `\xintFor*` loop:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

%% Thanks to egreg, make lrbox* global (requires etoolbox.sty):
\cslet{glrbox}\lrbox
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname glrbox\endcsname{\setbox}{\global\setbox}{}{}
\cslet{endglrbox}\endlrbox

\newsavebox{\myboxi}    
\newsavebox{\myboxii}   
\newsavebox{\myboxiii}
\newsavebox{\myboxiv}   
\newsavebox{\myboxv}

\newcounter{myboxes}

\def\numname#1{%
  \ifcase#1 \or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven \or twelve\or thirteen\or fourteen\or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eighteen\or nineteen\or twenty\fi%
}

\usepackage{xinttools}% for \xintFor/\xintFor* loops

\NewDocumentEnvironment{outerenv}{}{%
    \setcounter{myboxes}{0}%
}{%
    \tikz \node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=5,rectangle split ignore empty parts]
    {%
%        \foreach\nn in {1, ..., \themyboxes}
% xinttools manual says to use "\do" but we can use any token, such as ":"
        \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\value{myboxes}}}:
        {%
%        \edef\tmpname{\csname mybox\romannumeral##1\endcsname}%
%        \def\tmpnum{\numname{##1}}%
%        \nodepart{\tmpnum}\usebox{\tmpname}%
%        \nodepart{\numname{\nn}}\usebox{\csname mybox\romannumeral\nn\endcsname}%
        %\begingroup% just testing to confirm with it same error as in OP
        \nodepart{\numname{##1}}%
        %\endgroup % bien sûr \nodepart n'aime pas cela...
        \usebox{\csname mybox\romannumeral##1\endcsname}%
        }%
        %%%
        %% This works:
      % \nodepart{one}{\usebox{\myboxi}}
      % \nodepart{two}{\usebox{\myboxii}}
      % \nodepart{three}{\usebox{\myboxiii}}
      % \nodepart{four}{\usebox{\myboxiv}}
      % \nodepart{five}{\usebox{\myboxv}}%
    };%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{innerenv}{}{%
    \stepcounter{myboxes}%
    \edef\tmpname{\csname mybox\romannumeral\themyboxes\endcsname}%
    \begin{glrbox}{\tmpname}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
}{%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{glrbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{outerenv}

\begin{innerenv}
First
\end{innerenv}

\begin{innerenv}
Second
\end{innerenv}

\begin{innerenv}
Third
\end{innerenv}

\end{outerenv}

\end{document}
```